# Javascript facebook login - what is the best way to have a secure login?

Tags: javascript, facebook, security, authentication, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a login with facebook using javascript for a chrome extension that will return some data from the server.

I am currently able to login without issues with google and facebook.  Google is returning the email address and an unique ID that only applies to my app so I can use that ID to login into my server together with the email address provided.

Facebook returns the real user ID and the email address, meaning that anyone that has access to facebook can find that ID and if they know the email address they will be able to login.

As I do not want to ask the user to login every time that they restart the browser or every few days, what is the best way to get a unique constant secure ID from facebook that is unique to my application?

Naturally if I make it unique in the extension it would not really be beneficial because anyone can read the extension code and then figure out how to get someone else unique ID from their user ID.

The authorization code that Facebook sends is not constant, so I would not be able to send it to the server to authenticate someone.

Comment: Send the token to the server, and then make an API call to verify it is genuine. You do not want just to pass the user id - because anyone can send that to your app. (And to find a user id that “works” for your app would just be a matter of guesswork.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Facebook returns the real user ID" - wrong, the api only returns an App Scoped ID. And no one except for the user himself will be able to login. Just use the App Scoped ID, that´s how you identify users in your App. Btw, user IDs are not really something you need to keep secret. Access Tokens are.

Comment: I swear I read that it was returning the real ID... then I am good :-)  (yes, the auth code is secret, as well as the user ID and email...)  thank you